# base url not working in server while using excell reader

Tags: php, codeigniter, base-url

i doing excell file reader in my local is working fine, i giving the base url like this

> "C:/xampp/htdocs/school/uploads/staff_importFiles/".$sFileName

So my local is working fine,but when ever i uopload the code in my server it is not working , in my server base url i am ging like this

> "http://domain.in/school/uploads/staff_importFiles/".$sFileName

If i am giving means i am getting error like this

**The file http://domain.in/school/uploads/staff_importFiles/30e97727b3dc9f2ebe493fa3165b51c7.xls was not found**

inside this **staff_importFiles** folder my files is there , but don't know it throwing the error, i am using codeigniter,any one help me please

Comment: Try with `FCPATH.'uploads/staff_importFiles/'.$sFileName` instead. I think you are searching for absolute path, not url.

Comment: I tried it not working

Comment: You will have to show appropriate code. Start with controller.

Answer (score 2):

In codeigniter use base_url() function.

`<?php echo base_url().'uploads/stuff_importFiles/'.$sfileName ;?>`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have subdirectory named school in your local. While it does not exist on your server. So you should change your server url to.

> "http://domain.in/uploads/staff_importFiles/".$sFileName

While this is not recommended way of doing this. You should use **base_url()**